# adb doesn’t see phone device (Galaxy Apollo)

Tags: android, adb

I have an app I want to test on an actual phone and I’ve been trying to get it on to a Samsung Galaxy Apollo. The phone dosent seem to be reconised by adb and so I’ve started to investigate:

I’m running adb on a Windows XP (sp3) PC

The driver for my Samsung Galaxy Apollo seems to be running when the phone is connected I can see (via device manager->USB controllers) SAMSUNG USB Composite Device

The Phone is in debugging mode, on the phone I have 2 Notifications about the USB: “USB debugging connected” and “USB connected”

The USB driver for the PC came from Samsung official development site and was installed via the file SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe.

My problem is that in the command prompt when I put adb devices the phone isn’t found the list is empty.

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for 2 days now and have been through a lot of things to try and sort it out.

Things I have done:
Tried adb kill-server and adb start-server after the phone is connected – it still doesn’t get seen by adb

I have uninstalled the usb driver by running the uninstall program that came with the driver. Then I  reinstalled the drivers – it still doesn’t get seen by adb

I have uninstalled the driver via device manager then pluged the phone in (USB) and powered it and allowed the driver to automatically install when the PC detects new hardware (it installs the same drivers previously installed) – it still doesn’t get seen by adb

I didnt have a “adb_usb.ini” file in my /user/.android folder but I’m not sure if this is an old thing or a non windows thing. Anyway I created one with one line in with 0x04e8. Stopped the adb server and restarted it again this had no effect.

Can anyone help? I'm to the point where I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem and it turns out to be a firmware problem with Samsung phones.

If you find you have this problem the advice from [here](http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2010/12/24/How-to-repair-the-USB-not-detected-problem-on-Android-Samsung-phones) is gold dust.

The problem is that the phone some how changes USB mode in my case the UART had changed to modem instead of PDA. Once I changed this mode back to PDA it all worked.

To access this USB mode setting you must dial *#7284#, this brings up a utility screen which has 2 sections UART and USB both must be set to PDA. The advice is that even if both are set to PDA then set them from PDA and back to PDA.

After doing this I plugged my phone into the PC USB and I get a ADB device appear ADB Interface in “control panel->system->hardware->Device Manager” and the device shows up when typing “adb devices” in the platform-tools directory of the android sdk showing that adb can now see my device.

However this solution should only be a last resort as Anass points out make sure USB debugging is turned on and that the correct USB drivers are installed before resorting to this.

Answer (score 2):

First, try enabling USB debugging mode by going to Menu>Settings>Applications>Development>USB Debugging and then connect

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've done that, Sorry I didnt make it clear. Thats why I get the notification on the phone "USB debugging connected"

Answer (score 1):

To check if your USB connection is functional, connect the phone to a USB port, then run adb devices. On Linux this will look like this:

```
mano@kratos:~$ android/platform-tools/adb devices

List of devices attached 

6442b9d782a9    device
```

If there are no devices listed in the output of the adb devices command, follow ONE of the following steps and try again, preferably starting with the first (try again after EVERY step).

- Make sure USB debugging is on: Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging should be checked, this can only be done while not connected via USB already.
- Dial *#7284# and set both the UART and USB setting to "PDA", also if they are already showing PDA as setting. Just to be sure.
- As a final measure, resetting the phone to factory settings also works. Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset -> Reset phone. This will erase all data from your phone, including: your Google account, system and application data and settings, downloaded applications. It will not erase: Current system software and bundled applications, SD card files such as music or photos.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing massive issues getting ADB to work for my phone. It had been working at one stage prior to a firmware update (Now on Android 4.0.4 on a UK Samsung Galaxy s2 i9100) and it randomly stopped working. I'm on XP 64 and it may only be an issue for 64-bit operating systems.

USB debugging had always been set, the drivers were installed, but ADB would not work.

Numerous help guides all seem to concentrate on getting the correct drivers to install with Kies or with extracted drivers from Kies only but this was largely not my problem (or the drivers with kies for the Samsung S2 no longer allow ADB?) My phone is rooted with superuser and busybox only but otherwise has completely standard firmware (had been rooted and was unrooted when android 4.0.4 was upgraded).

So starting from a point with the drivers installed I can connect to my phone as an MTP, as a Camera, as a Mass Storage device and with Kies. I have Kies installed and have had it reinstall the drivers multiple times but this should probably work fine without Kies and just the latest drivers installed as available from here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956. I have a device listed in Device Manager "Samsung Android ADB Interface" with driver version "2.9.505.831" but no ADB.

It appeared I had an issue with the uart connection on my phone (as shown in the phoneutil screen) and also I needed to be able to install the adb interface driver from the google sdk.

I was able to do neither of these using the standard methods/guides I was able to find elsewhere.

To change the UART setting back to PDA and the USB connection back to PDA via the special dialler code *#7284# no longer works on the Samsung Galaxy s2 i9100 Android 4.0.4 (or at least not for me) - I had to download the bettercut apk (which I may very well had to pirate because I couldn't find it in the market) and made a shortcut to phoneutil manually.

bettercut > new shortcut > no > all activities > phoneutil

There you can change the settings to modem and back to pda (when connected in modem mode xp listed a new device "7 CDS's" which would not install).

After that I had to install the Google driver from the SDK (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver)

And to allow Windows XP 64 to install the drivers you need to edit "android_winusb.inf" to add the Samsung Galaxy as a valid device.

I added the following lines to [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64].

android_winusb.inf

```
[Google.NTx86]

; Samsung galaxy
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_00
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_04
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&adb
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&adb

[Google.NTamd64]

; Samsung galaxy
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_00
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_04
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&adb
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&adb
```

I found instructions to add a device USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_00 however this did not match my phone, I needed to manually determine the device ID and add it myself before windows would let me install the drivers.

Device Manager > Samsung Android Phone > Samsung Android ADB Interface > Properties > Details > Matching Device ID

And the phone ADB interface had the following ID: `USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&adb`

...which I added as above (if your phone doesn't match you would need to do this too I think). I then updated the driver for "Samsung Android ADB Interface" using the "Android Bootloader Interface" which I can now select from the Google SDK Driver.

Install "Android Bootloader Interface" from Google SDK.

I then was able to reinstall the "Samsung Android ADB Interface" driver as before or the "Android Composite ADB Interface" from the Google SDK and ADB started working (as tested with ADB Devices, mine is now listed, woot!).

So I think the problem was mainly the lack of the Android Bootloader Interface driver, with the UART thing possibly having some effect?

However I did have ADB working BEFORE I decided to re-root my phone (only discovered it stopped working when I couldn't use ADB Explorer however I am fairly certain I had used it not 10 minutes before). So why it stopped working I haven't a clue. I am pretty certain nothing changed on my PC, so perhaps setting the UART mode back and forcing the drivers to reinstall was enough to fix it. However maybe ADB no longer works for the standard Samsung drivers and you need to install the drivers from the SDK too?

I'd be interested to know if there are other folk in the same boat, if they have any idea what happened.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks for this. I was trying to get the ADB drivers working for the TI AM335x board, and was following instructions posted here: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android_ADB_Setup#adb_over_USB_on_Windows_Machine  Following your instructions to get the Hardware ID from Device Manager, and then add it to the inf file with the `&adb` at the end did the trick. I am now able to use it to debug in Android Studio over ADB.