# Can't set the usb drivers to debug in Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, usb, driver

I have a problem trying to debug in my Samsung Galaxy.
I have followed the instructions in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html#WinXp) and downloaded  the [Samsung USB Drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW) but when I get to the point of updating the driver I don't know which folder to pick. There are 26 folders inside SAMSUNG/USB DRIVERS.

Also, I've seen solutions in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848567/adb-samsung-galaxy) editing the **android-sdk-windows\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf**, but where is that folder anyway??

My OS is WinXP SP3.

Comment: Your SDK folder is whereever you downloaded it to. i.e. default: c:\users\yourusername\my documents\downloads

Comment: @Blundell, I know where my android-sdk folder is (which by the way is named by default as android-sdk, and not android-sdk-windows). Still it doesn't have any folder named usb_driver inside!

Comment: Run your SDK manager and ensure you have installed the package extra "USB-Drivers"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally decided to install [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) and adb recognizes my Galaxy Nexus now.

Comment: After double clicking on all sorts of things from samsung.com website, it was installing kies that put the drivers I needed in place, thanks!

Comment: Same for me, Kies was the only thing that worked (and even that required an update immediately after install).  Samsung has been by far the worst in supporting development of Android.  I have developed on Motorola, HTC and Acer Android devices.  And all Samsung has to do is to provide USB drivers!

Answer (score 2):

The instructions at: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1830108 worked for me. I only needed to follow the instructions upto before the 'Android Bootloader Interface Driver" section. The USB drivers available from the Samsung website were not recognized as valid drivers for my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: This got it working for me, having tried umpteen different things. The key part of the instructions is 'Make sure "Show All Devices" is selected' - that's where I'd been going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the path `C:\Program Files\SAMSUNG\USB Drivers` once you are updating the driver software inside the device manager. That worked for me.

On Device Manager:

- Right-Click the device driver
- 'Update Driver Software'
- click on 'Browse my Computer for driver Software'
- put path where it asks for it as `C:\Program Files\SAMSUNG\USB Drivers`

First of all if you haven't done it yet you should download the USB driver from [Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW).

Comment: That's what you would normally expect, just that it doesn't find/install any drivers from there.